# How to get minimum and maximum of function with complementary error function

Tags: derivatives, optimization, roots, error-function

Consider this function with the complementary error function [$\mathrm{erfc}(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html)
$$e^{2x} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{2} x\right) - \frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{1}{2}x} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\frac
{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
I am interested in finding the minimum and maximum of this function for $x \geq 1$, but I am not sure how I should approach this problem. Intuitively I would compute the derivative and set it to zero, but I have no idea how to get values for $x$ out of this thing
$$2 e^{2x} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{2} x\right) - \frac{4}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{2x - 2x^2} - \frac{1}{4} e^{\frac{1}{2}x} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\frac
{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\frac{1}{2} x - \frac{1}{2} x^2} = 0$$
I thought, this might be possible by using the bounds for $x > 0$ that are mentioned [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html), but I got stuck on something like
$$4 + \frac{3}{2} x - \frac{3}{2} x^2 + \ln\left(\frac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} - 1\right) - \ln\left(\frac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 4}} - 1\right) = 0$$

Would anyone have an idea how to find the minimum or the maximum of this function for $x \geq 1$? I am open both for analytical and numerical approaches.

Comment: for what stands $$erfc$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Complementary error function

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  $ erfc(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2)} \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}dt $

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I edited my question and added a link

Comment: is it $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\pi}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner no, it is $$\mathrm{erfc}(x) = 1 - \mathrm{erf}(x)$$ which is $$\mathrm{erfc}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, lower bound is x, mistakenly written it as $\pi$, corrected it now ... Correct form again : $ erfc(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2)} \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}dt $

Comment: is this the correct function? $${{\rm e}^{2\,x}}{\it erfc} \left( \sqrt {2}x \right) -1/2\,{{\rm e}^{x
/2}}{\it erfc} \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2}x \right) 
$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner no, it is $e^{2x} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{2}x\right) - \frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{x}{2}} \mathrm{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} x \right)$ (the first function in my question)

Comment: this is the same $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner True. I've overseen that one, sorry...

Comment: A quick brute-force search (using random double-precision arguments) suggests the following: $min \approx (-8.858782178){10}^{-2}$ near $1.565265$ and $max \approx (7.46257){10}^{-2}$ near $1$. We don't have to worry about error magnification for $\exp$ here when using binary floating-point arithmetic, and the error magnification in $\mathrm{erfc}$ should be minimal for these inputs.

Comment: @njuffa I got similar results from Wolfram Alpha... Do they use a brute force search as well or should there be "smarter" ways to get these minima? I should probably give up on analytical approaches, shouldn't I?

Comment: @MrTsjolder I am a software engineer, not a mathematician, and I don't have a good overview over analytical / numerical methods available for problems like these. This particular equation looked simple (and well conditioned) enough to attack by brute force search with random test vectors, and in fact required only a few minutes to find a solution good to almost single precision.